# (Android, iOS, Windows, Linux) Server Polling Vs Push vs Implement Server

Tags: android, ios, networking, push, polling

I'm building a multi-OS mirroring system which I would like to implement using a hybrid client-server and p2p communication method (at least that's the best way I have of describing it).

My issue is that at some point I have a central server (appengine, so there are limitations to what I could do because of time and networking capability constraints) that would need to get a message to a host of different devices which are not necessarily running the same OS (Windows, Android, iOS, Linux, etc...).

Android and iOS (or any other mobile platform) are the main problems it looks like I will be having on 2 levels.

1 - They are both limited by battery power (more so than a laptop and desktops shouldn't have that issue at all), so whichever method I use needs to take that into account.

2 - NAT (harder because the user has relatively less control over their firewall than on a network that they are running). My central server will maintain a table of which device has what IP address, but from what I understand if there is NAT or a firewall it won't be able to get to it if the port was not forwarded.

Since I will be writing a specific client for each OS I prefer a solution that is more universal. I have been leaning towards writing an extremely simple HTTP server that sits on each client and takes requests (which appengine is able to send) and treats them as messages that alert the client to perform an action (either with the server or another client). However, I run into the issue of NAT/firewall. For instance if appengine needs to send a message to AndroidDevice1 it would grab its IP address from a table and make a request to it. However this doesn't work if the ports aren't forwarded correctly, and if the user is on 3g/4g the firewall is controlled by the data provider.

Because of this, I started thinking about using Android C2DM but I want a solution I could implement across platforms.

The only other method I could think of is to just have the client poll the server for messages. This has the battery and network consumption issue though.

Would there be any other way to implement this, and if not, which one of the above methods are best in terms of balancing usability, power and data consumption and user input (the less the user has to do to get the client set up (ie port forwarding, etc...) the better)? Please note that I do not intend for this to become a discussion/flame war but a logical presentation of facts.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a persistent TCP connection from the device to the server and then communicate over this open connection. This would be a very simple connection with keepalive packets for the most part.

In theory this would consume some battery through the radio, but in practice I have experienced that the battery is not affected much at all. Key is to keep the communication over this line to a minimum.

If AppEngine does not allow this approach, you can run your own socket server and then communicate between this server and the appengine server using REST. A socket server I have used is Apache MINA and had no issues with scalability.

Another problem you will have with this approach or any other approach is that on iOS (afaik) you cannot keep a tcp socket open when the App goes into background. The only thing to communicate with the iOS device is Apple Push Notification Service

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is using REST any better/different than simply polling the server? What is the resource (battery & bandwidth) hit going to look like? And this is just another reason I dislike Apple :)

Comment: Polling the server will kill your battery very fast, not to mention the bandwidth usage. Persistent TCP connection just sits in the background not consuming much resources. REST is for connection between your AppEngine and Socket Server in case AppEngine does not allow running a Socket Server. There is no REST between the device and the Socket Server, its plain TCP based. In a persistent connection your battery will have a negligible hit. Atleast thats what I have experienced on my HTC Evo Android 2.3.4 and on my BlackBerry. No stats on iPhone (its not possible on iPhone sigh....)

Comment: In case this helps you can look at some sample code to do the persistent TCP connection. A couple of links: http://openmobster.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cloud/android/connection/src/main/java/org/openmobster/core/mobileCloud/android/module/connection/NotificationListener.java and http://openmobster.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cloud/android/connection/src/main/java/org/openmobster/core/mobileCloud/android/module/connection/NetSession.java

Comment: Much appreciated....maybe I just won't support iOS on principal AND out of necessity...

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer rather than having HTTP Connection you should create TCP/IP tunnel and make communication fast and reliable. I have one  Chat application which runs perfact for me using TCP/IP. If you use this you will have same logic for multiple platforms. Only thing you need to write is different code for iOS and android.

Comment: The problem with that is as far as I know you cannot do that on appengine.

Comment: True. In appengine you can do only http or https server. Then go for Pull mechanism. I have developed an application using Pull mechanism as well. so far no issue. Because I am not aware of Android C2DM connectivity with app engine. if it is , then it will be best to leverage the C2DM